# Supress bluetooth connection notifications by regex on the name of the connecting device

Tags: bluetooth, d-bus, notifications

I run a manjaro system with i3 as a window manager and the`blueman-applet`.

When I'm at work, the neighbours' machines continually connect and disconnect to my machine, resulting in annoying popups announcing that they have connected/disconnected.

I have tried blocking and untrusting these machines via the applet, but I still get these notifications.

Is there a way, via `dbus`, or `bluetoothctl`, or some other mechanism, to block all bluetooth notifications from any device whose name starts with a specific set of leading characters (all device names start with the string `MWAI`)

I'm quite happy to hack on a config file or knock up a shell script to enable this, just looking for a bit of direction on how best to proceed.

Comment: I tried this, to no avail:
```
#!/bin/bash

echo Blocking the following devices

bluetoothctl devices| grep MWAI 


for mac in $(bluetoothctl devices| grep MWAI | cut -f2 -d" ")
do
    bluetoothctl disconnect $mac
    bluetoothctl block $mac
    bluetoothctl untrust $mac
done

echo Done

```

Answer (score 0):

To suppress Bluetooth notifications for specific devices on a Manjaro system running i3 and using the blueman-applet, you can use a combination of dbus and shell scripting. Here’s a general approach to achieve this:

**Identify the Bluetooth Devices:** First, you need to identify the Bluetooth devices that are causing the issue. You can use bluetoothctl to list all paired devices and their details.

**Monitor Bluetooth Events:** You can monitor Bluetooth events using dbus-monitor. This tool listens to the D-Bus message bus system and outputs messages that match certain criteria.

**Filter Notifications:** Create a script that monitors these Bluetooth events and checks if the device name starts with "MWAI". If it does, suppress the notification.

Here’s a basic outline of how your script might look:

```
#!/bin/bash

dbus-monitor --system "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged'" |
while read -r line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -q "MWAI"; then
        # This is where you'll handle the suppression of notifications
        # Depending on how your system is set up, you might need to 
        # interact with your notification system or the Bluetooth service
        echo "Suppressed notification from device starting with MWAI"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks Kristtof -- I tried your command above and got an error: 

dbus-monitor: unable to enable new-style monitoring: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied